# DinkToPdf footer not working when there is an image

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, dinktopdf

I'm using DinkToPdf library in a .NET 7 web application to create a pdf. However, when I include a pdf in the footer, it does not work.

This is the code for generating the pdf.

```
var html = await _templateEngine.RenderAsync("Views/CalibrationCertificate.cshtml", calibrationCertificate);

var basePath = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
var footerViewPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "Resources", "Footer.html");

var doc = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
{
    GlobalSettings = {
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
        Orientation = Orientation.Portrait
    },
    Objects = {
        new ObjectSettings()
        {
            HtmlContent = html,
            FooterSettings = new()
            {
                HtmUrl = footerViewPath,
            }
        }
    }
};

var result = _htmlToPdfConverter.Convert(doc);
```

This is the contents of Footer.html.

```
<div class="hr mt-2 mb-5 page-break-avoid" />

<div class="row mt-2 page-break-avoid">
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center">

    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <img src='logo.jpg' />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my folder structure.
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tXvk.png)

This is the build properties of logo.jpg.
[build properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcwTq.png)

Generated pdf file is empty (when downloaded using blazor client app).
[generated pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDd5u.png)

I'm new here, so please excuse if I have violated any guidelines.

I tried all the suggestions I could find in the internet.